# Is it possible to give the size of the modal in the options

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal to show messages:

```
 var options = {
          backdrop: false,
          keyboard: true,
          backdropClick: false,
          templateUrl: 'a.html',
          controller: 'aController',  
        };
 var modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
```

Is it possible to give the custom width and height style properties?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can provide a `size` key value(sm, md, lg) which interpolates to `.modal-sm, .modal-md and .modal-lg`.

As stated in the **[angular-bootstrap documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)**:

> size - optional size of modal window. Allowed values: 'sm' (small) or
>   'lg' (large). Requires Bootstrap 3.1.0 or later

***Javascript***

```
 var options = {
          backdrop: false,
          keyboard: true,
          backdropClick: false,
          templateUrl: 'a.html',
          controller: 'aController',
          size: 'lg' // sm, md, lg
 };
 var modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
```

If you are not satisfied with the size provided by those values, then you have two options:

[**1**] Add a class to the top level modal window using the `windowClass` attribute and then use this class to change the respective elements via css child selectors.

[**2**] You can also change the template using the `windowTemplateUrl` and override the default template implementation or create one yourself.

Answer (score 11):

[Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) applies a conditional class to each modal based on what string is passed in as a size option to modalInstance.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" ng-class="size ? 'modal-' + size : ''">
```

You can pass in a custom string to create a class in the format modal-[yourSizeString]. Extend the default modal sizes by passing in `size: 'xl'` or something similar to generate the class `modal-xl` which can be styled with a custom width.

**JS**

```
myOpenFunc = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'mypage.html',
        size: 'xl',
        controller: 'myCtrl'
    });
};
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-xl {
    width: 1200px;
}
```